# insert into select on duplicate key update

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, on-duplicate-key

I'm try to create a database where i save users search.

I want insert term when this term don't exist and adding +1 when exist but all other specific field on database are the same.

Example:

user1 search playstation with price 1 = insert into database

user2 search playstation with price 1 = +1 on the same row generated by user1

user3 search playstation with price 1 and condition new = insert into database a new record

I have write this but don't work:

```
      <?php 
     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "keyword");

   // Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    // attempt insert query execution

     $sql = "INSERT INTO keyword (id, search, category, mn, mx, site, itmcond, free, sortorder, type, payp) VALUES ('".$_GET["id"]."', '".$_GET["search"]."', '".$_GET["category"]."', '".$_GET["mn"]."', '".$_GET["mx"]."', '".$_GET["site"]."', '".$_GET["itmcond"]."', '".$_GET["free"]."', '".$_GET["sortorder"]."', '".$_GET["type"]."', '".$_GET["payp"]."')";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";

        } else{
           echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .          mysqli_error($link);

             }

         // close connection
           mysqli_close($link);
       ?>
```

Anyone can help me to understand where use INSERT INTO for add search to database, SELECT for find the term previously insered and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for adding +1 for the same search.

Thanks!

Comment: try to make it the search query as a primary key and check if it searched before, if it is then increase its count. Keep the track of count using one more column.

Comment: Can you explane me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO keyword (id, search, category, mn, mx, site, itmcond, free, sortorder, type, payp) VALUES ('".$_GET["id"]."', '".$_GET["search"]."', '".$_GET["category"]."', '".$_GET["mn"]."', '".$_GET["mx"]."', '".$_GET["site"]."', '".$_GET["itmcond"]."', '".$_GET["free"]."', '".$_GET["sortorder"]."', '".$_GET["type"]."', '".$_GET["payp"]."')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
  //add this
  die();

    } else{
       echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .          mysqli_error($link);

         }

     // close connection
       mysqli_close($link);
   ?>
```